# HTML Canvas does not render until I resize the window

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am building a website that lets users draw in real-time together. When a user joins, they send a request to the server for any existing draw data, which is then received and rendered on a canvas. This is done using websockets (with socket.io), and the code is very simple.

Server:

```
socket.emit('draw_data', data);
```

Client:

```
socket.on('draw_data', (data) => {
  for (var i of data) {
    drawPoint(i);
  }
});
```

This process works as expected 70% of the time. The other 30%, nothing will show up on the canvas unless I resize the window. I've tried some hacky fixes like rendering twice, but that doesn't do anything. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I've never run into anything similar, and you haven't shared enough code that I could even begin guessing usefully. Could you add some more code?

Comment: Clearly, there's a race condition somewhere, but this isn't enough code to say where and provide a definitive answer. Please share a [mcve].